# Could a mod please undelete the question about stalking?

Tags: support

As meta.SF regulars will recall [a user](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/51341/trevor-burnham) recently posted a question here accusing [another user](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/14428/hobodave) of stalking him and maliciously downvoting.  It appears that as the discussion of [the original question](https://serverfault.com/questions/241823/setting-a-time-limit-for-a-transaction-in-mysql-innodb) played out on SF and as the comments and responses to the stalking accusation accumulated here (most of which said that there was no stalking or any other malicious behaviour), [the person in question](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/51341/trevor-burnham) decided to withdraw their accusation.

I would like to see that question restored here (and locked if necessary) because I think that sort of vigorous discussion is good to have and good to be recorded.  How a person or - in this case - community deals with conflict is an excellent indicator of what the community is really like.  I don't think that question should be deleted just because [trevor](https://meta.serverfault.com/users/51341/trevor-burnham) didn't want it here anymore.

OTOH, this question should be deleted once that question is restored...

Answer (score 5):

For the record, I did vote to close that "question". It wasn't really a question so much as a user venting his unjustified anger. Having it on the site merely drags the standard down - a LOT.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that I agree that it should be undeleted.

10k+ users can still see it, and the URL is http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1290/.   It appears that Zypher decided to delete the question, not Trevor Burnham.  Perhaps Zypher will leave a comment here.

Comment: The original poster asked for it to be deleted so Zypher did.

Comment: and that should be the end of the story.

Comment: There is a very good reason why it was deleted, as asked by the OP, so it is going to stay that way.

Comment: just a quick Chopper and Mark beat me to the reason.